# Kubernetes federation

Tags: kubernetes

I have two eks cluster added in kubernetes federation , I am able to deploy pod on each cluster by adding labels in deployment for each cluster , but I am not able to do the same randomly , if I run the deployment it should be able to deploy pods of any one cluster randomly without adding any labels

I am sharing the crd file

```
apiVersion: types.kubefed.io/v1beta1
kind: Placement
metadata:
  name: random-placement
spec:
  clusters:
    - clusterSelector: {}
      random: {}
```

> Error validating "crd-random.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Placement): unknown field "spec" in io.kubefed.types.v1beta1.Placement; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

I am getting this error kubefedctl version - kubefedctl version: version.Info{Version:"v0.10.0-4-gd6f10d29", GitCommit:"d6f10d29c3785dc55abc954dec0afeddce4893ef", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-05-10T10:06:35Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Need help on this